# How to assign keyboard shortcut for arrow keys(i.e. ctrl + j for left arrow) in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Recently, I am using VISUAL STUDIO 2022. While coding, I find it irritating to move my finger to the arrow keys to move the cursor. So, in vscode, I made some keybindings for moving the cursor left, right, up, and down.

But! in VISUAL STUDIO 2022 , I don't understand how to do that.
I want these keyboard shortcuts in VISUAL STUDIO.

- ctrl + j  : move cursor left
- ctrl + k  : move cursor down
- ctrl + l  : move cursor right
- ctrl + i  : move cursor up

I tried to go to the keyboard options in VISUAL STUDIO 2022 but didn't find any options regarding this.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by configuring keyboard shortcuts for the following commands: Edit.CharRight, Edit.CharLeft, Edit.LineUp, Edit.LineDown.

If you want to be able to extend the selection (e.g. Shift+Ctrl+L multiple times to select multiple characters), there are a separate set of commands with Extend appended to the name (Edit.CharRightExtend, etc).

Answer (score 0):

On the menu bar, choose Tools > Options.

Expand Environment, and then choose Keyboard.

Optional: Filter the list of commands by entering all or part of the name of the command, without spaces, in the Show commands containing box.

In the list, choose the command to which you want to assign a keyboard shortcut.

In the Use new shortcut in list, choose the feature area in which you want to use the shortcut.

For example, you can choose Global if you want the shortcut to work in all contexts. You can use any shortcut that isn't mapped (as Global) in another editor. Otherwise, the editor overrides the shortcut.