# How to assign a shortcut to an arrow key in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2022

I want to assign `Ctrl+Alt+<Arrow Left>` as the keyboard shortcut for `View.NavigateBackward` in Visual Studio 2022, because I am used to this from VS Code.

However, the "Press shortcut keys" textfield in the settings does not seem to register arrow keys. I can only input Ctrl/Shift/Alt and Letters/Numbers.

So how can I assign a shortcut to an arrow key?

Comment: Worked fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XTg4.png Not sure why it isn't for you.

Comment: This answer might help you @Finni https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990265/how-to-assign-keyboard-shortcut-for-arrow-keysi-e-ctrl-j-for-left-arrow-in/78199323#78199323